# How to pass Multiple two-dimensional list, lists and variables using JsonResult as return from a controller to a view in Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax, jsonresult

I am trying to pass the single and two-dimensional list of data from a controller to view using JsonResult in asp.net MVC 5

**In Controller**

```
 public JsonResult floatingFloorCalc(double roomlen, double roomwid, double roomhgt, int nmOpSde, double roomvol, int msurmnt, double[] tAreaArrVal, int[] dIndxArrVal, int spl63val, int spl125val, int spl250val, int spl500val, int spl1kval, int spl2kval, int spl4kval, int spl8kval, int afiltCor, double equiplen, double equipwid, double equiphgt, int plintReq, double plintlen, double plintwid, double plinthgt, double plintdnsty, double distnFloor1, double distnFloor2, double distnFloor3, double distnFloor4, int mthrslbthck, int fltflrslbthck, double re63, double re125, double re250, double re500, double re1k, double re2k, double re4k, double re8k, int ncrid)
    {
        tbic tb = new tbic();
        tb.tbic_calc(roomlen, roomwid, roomhgt, roomvol, msurmnt, tAreaArrVal, dIndxArrVal, out double totalRoomArea, out double roomVolInFt, out List<List<double>> listAllCoefficeint, out List<List<double>> listAreaCoefMulti, out List<double> listAreaCoefSum, out List<double> airAbsorpConst, out List<double> listAirAbsorption, out List<double> listRoomObsoprtion, out List<double> listRoomConstant);

        List<double> splLvlList = new List<double> { spl63val, spl125val, spl250val, spl500val, spl1kval, spl2kval, spl4kval, spl8kval };
        bool aFiltr = Convert.ToBoolean(afiltCor);
        List<double> DistanceFromFloorList = new List<double> { distnFloor1, distnFloor2, distnFloor3, distnFloor4 };
        List<double> roomEffectList = new List<double> { re63, re125, re250, re500, re1k, re2k, re4k, re8k };

        tspl tspl = new tspl();
        tspl.chiller1(splLvlList, aFiltr, nmOpSde, DistanceFromFloorList, listRoomConstant, roomEffectList, ncrid, mthrslbthck, fltflrslbthck);

        loadCalculations lc = new loadCalculations();
        lc.calc_Plinth(plintlen, plintwid, plinthgt, plintdnsty);            

        return Json(? , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

-- ? = How to pass so many output parameters to view.

**Class tbic.tbic_calc**
Following are the output variables returned from the method

```
public class tbic
{
    //Creating the instance of the dbmodel
    db_eaciEntities _eaciEntities = new db_eaciEntities();

    public void tbic_calc(double roomlen, double roomwid, double roomhgt, double roomvol, int msurmnt, double[] tAreaArrVal, int[] dIndxArrVal, out double totalRoomArea, out double roomVolInFt, out List<List<double>> listAllCoefficeint, out List<List<double>> listAreaCoefMulti, out List<double> listAreaCoefSum, out List<double> airAbsorpConst, out List<double> listAirAbsorption, out List<double> listRoomObsoprtion, out List<double> listRoomConstant)
    {            
        #region Intialize the output variables
        totalRoomArea = 0;
        double totalRoomAreaInFt = 0;
        roomVolInFt = 0;
        listAllCoefficeint = new List<List<double>>();
        listAreaCoefMulti = new List<List<double>>();
        listAreaCoefSum = new List<double>();
        listAirAbsorption = new List<double>();
        listRoomObsoprtion = new List<double>();
        listRoomConstant = new List<double>();
        #endregion

        for (int x = 0; x < dIndxArrVal.Count(); x++)
        {
            //fetch coeffcient id
            int indx = dIndxArrVal[x];

            //Fetch the total area of same surface type
```

}

**Similarly the output variables from Tspl.chiller**
Which are both lists and two-dimensional lists and some variables

The output lists contain data that needed to be displayed on to the view. 
Tried to pass these to another list so that a single list can be passed view ajax data but when passing two-dimensional list it gives me an error can't convert double[] to double.

I have encountered a roadblock on; 
**How to pass these lists data from a controller to view to display as I am using JsonResult to calculation on button click**

Comment: You need to pass back class that contains all the data you want to return and then pass an instance of that as a json result.

Comment: I couldn't get you, so you telling me to create another class that accept all parameters and pass that parameter to different methods and the output result I need, pass the instance of that one newly created class to retrieve the data. Right?